# What happens if I let cookies live forever on users computers

Tags: cookies, browser

What happens if I let cookies live forever on users
computers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the expiry date when creating the cookie

```
Set-Cookie: name=Mike; expires=Sat, 03 May 2025 17:44:22 GMT
```

---

NOTE: subject and text of question amended from "can I tell how long a cookie lives on a users computer" whilst I was typing my answer!

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I had a change of heart.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't set an expiry date, they automatically expire when the web browser is closed. If you specify a long time in the future, your cookie will remain for as long as the web browser allows (i.e. if the end user clears their cookies, etc. then it'll go, and some web browsers may enforce a maximum validity time)